# IControllerFactory errors in event log

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my web project, I have a custom IControllerFactory that uses StructureMap to build my Controller instances.  The factory works exactly as it should, and the website responds perfectly, however, the event log ends up getting flooded with messages that look like:

The IControllerFactory 'MyCustomNamespace.StructureMapControllerFactory' did not return a controller for the name 'fancybox'.

This is just one example, but there are others for static resources (css, js, images, etc.) beyond just the 'fancybox' stuff.  All these errors make it difficult to track down real problems, because it's difficult to find problems among all the noise, so my question is, has anyone come across this issue before, and if so, how did you configure the site to avoid these errors cluttering up the EventLog?

TIA, -J

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but I've recently run into the same issue, the problem was that there was a PNG image referenced in two CSS files that did not exist on the disk and weren't used by the application. Removing the references from the CSS fixed the issue.

In the Event Log, scroll down to where it tells you the request URL and check to make sure the item (image, script, style-sheet etc.) actually exists.